# Django testing how to make a request as logged in user?

Tags: django, django-testing

In Django tests, I want to log in and make a request.
Here the code

```
    def test_something(self):
        
        self.client.login(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy("my_releases"))
        self.assertEqual(response, 200)
```

But the code doesn't work and returns

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

How to make request in test as logged in user?

Comment: How did you create the user that you aim to login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation on **`.login(…)`** says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login):

> (…)
>
> `login()` returns True if it the credentials were accepted and login
> was successful.
>
> Finally, you’ll need to **remember to create user accounts** before
> you can use this method.

The tests run normally on a separate database, and thus the items created while debugging, or in production, do not have effect on that.

You thus first create a user and then test it with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# …

    def test_something(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects.create_user('my-user-name', email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD))
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy("my_releases"))
        self.assertEqual(response, 200)
```

The standard authentication engine works with a username and password, not with an email and password, so if you used the builtin authentication manager, you login with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# …

    def test_something(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects.create_user('my-user-name', email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='my-user-name', password=PASSWORD))
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy("my_releases"))
        self.assertEqual(response, 200)
```